# Binding multiple Textbox texts to a single List or String Array

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a TextBox inside all my DataGrid headers.

I was able to bind each TextBox text to different strings using the below code.

But I want to bind(two way) all the texts to a single list or an array of strings. Is there any way to do that?

**EDIT #1 :** What I want to achieve is to bind texts of the different textboxes to a single entity. It can be a List, Array, Class or anything.

XAML :

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>                                    
                        <TextBox  Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:TestDataGrid}}, Path=strName}"/>                                        
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel >
                        <<TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>                                    
                        <TextBox  Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:TestDataGrid}}, Path=strAge}"/>           
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

C# :

```
public partial class TestDataGrid : Page
{
    public String strName { get; set; }
    public String strAge { get; set; }

    public TestDataGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();                                  
    }

    onSomeEvent ()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("" + strName);
        MessageBox.Show("" + strAge);
    }
}
```

Comment: The only way you could achieve that is by using a converter with multibinding, so that to pass the array, and the index in the list / the entire list. It is a pain to achieve two way binding to lists  / array of Strings. Why no use a class that contains your string value, and that should be notifiable?

Comment: To get a two-way binding, you have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, so i think that this is not possible with your requirements.

Comment: @Sajith Sageer It's not clear what to what you want to bind? List of strings two way to the TextBox?

Comment: @Rekshino I want to bind texts from all the texboxs to a single list, it can be a list of strings

Comment: @LupuSilviu I can use a class too. I have edited the question. I  can't figure out how to bind them to a class either

Comment: What you actually want, is to have a single List, with all the strName+strAge from the DataGrid, right? Something like a summary of all the entries.

Comment: @LupuSilviu Yes.. i just want all the values in a single list.. and if a textbox value changes, it should reflect on the list..

Answer (score 1):

You need a class for each entry,

```
   class MyEntry : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private String _strName, _strAge;

    public String StrAge
    {
        get { return _strAge; }
        set
        {
            _strAge = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("StrAge");
        }
    }

    public String StrName
    {
        get { return _strName; }
        set
        {
            _strName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("StrName");
        }
    }

    public MyEntry()
    {

    }

    public MyEntry(String name, String age)
    {
        StrName = name;
        StrAge = age;
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(String propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

Then, you need to an array of classes in a ViewModel that will be bound to your View.

```
 class ViewModel
{
    public List<MyEntry> ListOfEntries { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        ListOfEntries = new List<MyEntry>();
        AddDefaultEntries();
    }

    private void AddDefaultEntries()
    {
        ListOfEntries.Add(new MyEntry("Candidate1", "29"));
        ListOfEntries.Add(new MyEntry("Candidate2", "20"));
    }
}
```

And then Bind the ViewModel to the View list this:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ViewModel _viewModel;
    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        _viewModel = new ViewModel();
        this.DataContext = _viewModel;
    }
}
```

The XAML code changes as followed:

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfEntries}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Name" Binding="{Binding StrName}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Age" Binding="{Binding StrAge}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfEntries}"
              IsHitTestVisible="False" Focusable="False">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding StrName}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Age" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding StrAge}"/>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

Hope this at least helps guide you to the right direction.